# Java - how to load method inside class it is defined?

Tags: java, class, methods, void

For example I have this code:

```
public class A
{
    private void my_method(){
        //do something
    }
}
```

So how can I call that method for code below to use it?
I saw in one example it was done like this:

```
public class A
{
    public A {
        my_method();
    }

    //some other code

    private void my_method(){
        //do something
    }
}
```

But trying this gives me this error:

"Syntax error on token "public", class expected after this token"

And of course using advise in error, gives this error:

"The nested type A cannot hide an enclosing type"
So it seems that code I saw is bad or somehow I'm doing something wrong. Anyone could explain how to do it properly in Java?

Comment: Without the _actual_ code, we won't be able to advise...

Comment: forgot to add the braces it should be public A() { instead of public A {

Comment: constructor is missing (). use public A()

Comment: @dbw thanks. That worked. It seems it was mistake in a code I saw. You can post in as answer, so everyone would see if someone gets the same problem :)

Comment: @Andrius thanks for reply, we are here to solve your problems and my comment could solve your problem that's more then enough rather then  posting an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

constructor is missing (). use

`public A()
  {
  }`

Answer (score 7):

Your [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) is wrong (you forgot the brackets).

It has to be

```
public A() {

}
```

Comment: parentheses, not brackets

Comment: That wouldn't be confusing at all if all programmers started saying brackets to all the types of brackets.

Comment: `Brackets extends Parentheses`.

Comment: I really didn't know this definition. It is correct, so. But I'd rather keep saying parentheses for a matter of clarification.

Comment: @MarounMaroun actually, it is the oppose, parentheses extends brackets, right?

Comment: @Math Actually I didn't consider the details, it was a joke (a bad one) :D

Comment: Well.. Perhaps I have to stop correcting people, your joke is good, I liked :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have not wrote the constructor correctly.
It should be:

```
public A() {
    my_method();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Jeroen's answer as it seems you are quite new to Java:

Your private method can be called from inside another method in your class.  E.g.

```
public class A
{
    public void anotherMethod() {
        my_method();
    }

    private void my_method(){
        //do something
    }
}
```

The code you provided was called within the constructor of the class.  This is a special method which is called when an object of type `A` is constructed e.g. `new A();`.  You can tell it's a constructor because it has no return type specified:

```
public A() {
}
```

rather than a normal method:

```
public void a() {
}
```

Something to note there is that in Java it is convention (but not strictly required) to name normal methods with a lowercase first letter and classes/objects/constructors with an upper case first letter.

So your mistake was that in your constructor you had not put `()` after the method name (`A` in this case).